# Are old profile pictures retained anywere on the SE network or on Imgur?

Tags: support, profile-page

Does Stack Overflow (and Imgur) delete an old profile picture when a new one is uploaded?

I have changed my profile picture and now, when I click "Change picture" again, I don't see the previous uploaded picture, but only the new one and the "Identicon".
One *year* ago I uploaded a personal picture, and now I would like to delete it from Stack communities and Imgur.

Comment: If you still have the hotlink to the image, it probably still is on imgur.

Comment: In "Edit your profile", if I click on "Change picture", I no longer see my personal picture; so, it's sure it was deleted from Stack Overflow and Imgur? I don't have any link to the old image.

Comment: If you do a right click on your current profile, you can see the "image location" or something similar. If you click that it shows a link to Imgur. If you knew the link to your old image, you could check if its still there. My guess is that it still will be online.

Comment: @Luuklag: I don't know the link of my old picture; that' s the problem: how can I check if my picture is still on Imgur?

Comment: Maybe there is a wayback machine version of any of your old contributions? Then you could check if the image is still around somewhere.

Comment: @Rob thanks, this is the link at the "Identicon". As Luuklag said, I'm trying with a wayback machine...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Images uploaded to the Stack Exchange Imgur account are never deleted, and a log is kept of profile image changes made on a user account, which moderators can access. The log records profile image URLs and for Imgur images that means moderators can access the old images still.

So no, old profile pictures are not deleted, provided you used imgur.

Your previous profile picture *on Stack Overflow* (where I am a moderator) was a gravatar image, which you can change at any time. The logged URL for the image now produces a standard geometric image. The last time you uploaded a profile picture to imgur was in 2016, at least according to the logs on your Stack Overflow account. I assume it was this image you wanted to remove, I think it is still shown as an option next time the gravatar option until you replace it with a different upload.

While it is indeed a personal picture, I’ll not produce the URL here as I am not sure if you’d want the URL to be public at this time or if Imgur honours deletion requests for the SE Imgur site from outsiders.

Since you can set different profile images per site in the Stack Exchange network I can’t see if you used imgur on other sites where I am not a moderator. Only employees can see that level of detail.